# Equivalent of Ubuntu’s write-mime-multipart?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, unix

I would like to generate a multipart mime-encoded document for use as user data on EC2 instances.

On Ubuntu, one is supposed to use [`write-mime-multipart`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/write-mime-multipart.1.html) to do this, as per [these instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CloudInit).

Does anyone know what would the OSX command-line equivalent be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I’ve found a simple solution. Ubuntu’s `write-mime-multipart` command is actually a Python script, [available here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lovelysystems/cloud-init/master/tools/write-mime-multipart) (or on an Ubuntu distro I guess).

I’ve simply downloaded this script to use. Perhaps not ideal with respect to version control, but okay for a simple script I think.

Better approaches welcome!

Comment: Thanks! This is great. I changed it to #!/usr/local/bin/python (instead of specifying v2.6) and installed the script to /usr/local/Cellar/write-mime-multipart, chmod +x and symlink it into /usr/local/bin to be more like brew. Worked fine. You can also run a Docker instance of Ubuntu to get it. ;-)

Comment: Cheers. Sounds like a good approach!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the script to work, so I put together a different one [here](https://gist.github.com/sshevlyagin/d450f15ba0fcc8990a2d4a77b954011d)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
# Usage
# python utils/multi.py /path/to/cloud.cfg:text/cloud-config /path/to/script.sh:text/x-shellscript

import sys
import email
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print("%s input-file:type ..." % (sys.argv[0]))
    sys.exit(1)

combined_message = MIMEMultipart()
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
    (filename, format_type) = i.split(":", 1)
    with open(filename) as fh:
        contents = fh.read()
    sub_message = MIMEText(contents, format_type, sys.getdefaultencoding())
    sub_message.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; file    name="%s"' % (filename))
    combined_message.attach(sub_message)

msg = email.message_from_string(combined_message.as_string())

for part in msg.walk():
    if part.get_content_maintype() == 'text':
        if part['Content-Transfer-Encoding'] in {'quoted-printable', 'base64'}:
            payload = part.get_payload(decode=True)
            del part['Content-Transfer-Encoding']
            part.set_payload(payload)
            email.encoders.encode_7or8bit(part)

# Send the modified message to stdout
print(msg.as_bytes().decode(encoding='UTF-8'))
```

Sources:
[StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095403/pythons-email-message-as-string-encodes-some-parts-as-base64-unclear-why)
[CloudInit Docks](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/format.html)

Comment: Please answer with more tan a link. The answer should be understandable when thr links disappear